# UIPageViewController with animation crashes application

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I programatically wrote a `UIPageViewController` into my iOS app. However, when I set the next ViewController like this:

```
pageContainer.setViewControllers([pages[currentIndex + 1]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

my entire app crashes.

Now from what I found, there are two fixes to this problem:

1. Set the `UIPageViewController`'s `transitionStyle` to `.pageCurl` (which provides me with an incredibly ugly and unwanted animation)
2. Or set the `animated` property to false when setting as new ViewController (Which then gives me no animation whatsoever, and thus is also unwanted)..

Does anyone know a way around this? Since neither of these options is probably gonna fly with my client...

Thanks!

-- Edit

As asked: The crash message:

```
2018-02-25 13:09:25.728651+0100 WAMP[22669:601029] *** Assertion failure in -[UIPageViewController _flushViewController:animated:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UIPageViewController.m:2137
2018-02-25 13:09:25.855963+0100 WAMP[22669:601029] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Don't know about flushed view <UIView: 0x7fcdc5d167c0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000644b90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000022daa0>>'
```

A complete code sample:

```
class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    var pageContainer: UIPageViewController!
    var currentIndex: Int? = 0
    var pendingIndex: Int?

    private(set) lazy var pages: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newStep(step: "One"), self.newStep(step: "Two"), self.newStep(step: "Three"), self.newStep(step: "Four")]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pageContainer = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        pageContainer.delegate = self
        pageContainer.setViewControllers([pages[0]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        view.addSubview(pageContainer.view)

    }

    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.pendingIndex = (self.currentIndex!) + 1
        self.currentIndex = (self.currentIndex!) + 1
        self.pageContainer.setViewControllers([self.pages[self.currentIndex!]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func newStep(step: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboardingStep\(step)")
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!

        if currentIndex == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                                viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!


        if currentIndex == pages.count-1 {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        pendingIndex = pages.index(of: pendingViewControllers.first!)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed {
            currentIndex = pendingIndex
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the crash message?

Comment: @Steve I added the crash message for you. Sorry for my late response.

Comment: Interesting, I’m seeing a lot of people asking similar questions. Would it be possible for you to add a complete sample of the code you’ve written. I tried setting up an example and used scroll transition but have yet to recreate this issue.

Comment: @Steve Added! :-)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I’ll dive into this and see if I can figure out what’s going on. Will reply if/when I solve this.

Comment: Not a computer yet but out of curiosity are you attempting to allow the user to use navigation buttons as well as being able to swipe on the screen or is it just navigation via the buttons?

Comment: The reason I ask about scrolling is, it looks like you have the viewController before / after data source methods but aren't setting the data source on the page vc. That makes these two methods unused. You can delete them. (that being said I've yet to replicate the crash with the code you've provided) you're running on a simulator correct? If so which one and what version of iOS.

Comment: I'm also curious, where did you place the button that calls nextButtonPressed? Is it on the OnboardingViewController? If so how are you keeping the pagevc you're adding to the view from covering the button when you add it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Steve The swiping was enabled at first, however, we disabled it after a certain period of time, which is why the methods are still there haha. The app crashes on simulator (iOS 11.2) and on my iPhone 8 (11.2.5). The next button is done by a `view.bringSubview(toFront: _)` call inside `viewDidLoad`. Just found out I missed that line when composing the example above.

Comment: Does the example crash for you?

Comment: @Steve Yes it does. Perhaps something to do with the content within some of the `UITableViewCell`'s. All of them include at least one `UILabel`, some of them include a `UITextField`.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like the base code (what you've provided above is sound). Is it possible to put a full crashing example in a public repo on GH for me to look at? If not I would suggest removing extra pieces from your crashing example until it behaves correctly, then working forward piece by piece as that would allow you to see what addition resulted in the issue.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? It work's fine when `animation: false` but crashes when changing the pages quickly if animation is true

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set up the data souse of UIPageViewController before setting view controllers directly. Transition style .scroll is required data source for page caching.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pageContainer = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        pageContainer.delegate = self
        pageContainer.dataSource = self
        pageContainer.setViewControllers([pages[0]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        view.addSubview(pageContainer.view)

    }
```